# Calculate DV01 for a vanilla swal for MXN index using quantlib

Tags: programming, swaps, quantlib

I am trying to calculate dv01 for a vanilla swap using quantlib. Its a MXN TIIE Swaps for built an index like

```
tiie_index = IborIndex('TIIE', Period(28, Days), 2, MXNCurrency(), NullCalendar(), Following, False, Actual360())
```

which I then pass in the swaphelpers. What I want to know how can I create the similar index for passing to the vanillaswap object. At the moment is Euribor6M(forecastTermStructure) but that doesnt seem right.
if I do tiie_index(forecastTermStructure), then it throws an error.

```
index=Euribor6M(forecastTermStructure)
```

```
from QuantLib import *

# global data
calendar = TARGET()
todaysDate = Date(16, April, 2021)
Settings.instance().evaluationDate = todaysDate
settlementDate = Date(20, April, 2021)

# market quotes
deposits = {
    (1, Months): 0.04289,
    (3, Months): 0.04289,
    (6, Months): 0.04345,
    (9, Months): 0.04401,

}

swaps = {
    (1, Years): 0.04506,
    (2, Years): 0.04881,
    (3, Years): 0.05262,
    (4, Years): 0.05575,
    (5, Years): 0.05817,
    (7, Years): 0.06212,
    (10, Years): 0.06639,
    (15, Years): 0.07074,
    (20, Years): 0.07303,
    (30, Years): 0.0741}

# convert them to Quote objects
for n, unit in deposits.keys():
    deposits[(n, unit)] = SimpleQuote(deposits[(n, unit)])
for n, unit in swaps.keys():
    swaps[(n, unit)] = SimpleQuote(swaps[(n, unit)])

# build rate helpers

dayCounter = Actual360()
settlementDays = 2
depositHelpers = [DepositRateHelper(QuoteHandle(deposits[(n, unit)]),
                                    Period(n, unit), settlementDays,
                                    calendar, Following,
                                    False, dayCounter)
                  for n, unit in [(1, Months), (3, Months),
                                  (6, Months), (9, Months)]]

fixedLegFrequency = EveryFourthWeek
fixedLegTenor = Period(28, Days)
fixedLegAdjustment = Following
fixedLegDayCounter = Actual360()
floatingLegTenor = Period(28, Days)
floatingLegAdjustment = Following
# create index
tiie_index = IborIndex('TIIE', Period(28, Days), 2, MXNCurrency(), NullCalendar(), Following, False, Actual360())
swapHelpers = [SwapRateHelper(QuoteHandle(swaps[(n, unit)]),
                              Period(n, unit), calendar,
                              fixedLegFrequency, fixedLegAdjustment,
                              fixedLegDayCounter, tiie_index)
               for n, unit in swaps.keys()]

# term structure handles

discountTermStructure = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()
forecastTermStructure = RelinkableYieldTermStructureHandle()

# term-structure construction

helpers = depositHelpers + swapHelpers
depoSwapCurve = PiecewiseFlatForward(settlementDate, helpers, Actual360())

swapEngine = DiscountingSwapEngine(discountTermStructure)

# 5Y Swap

nominal = 10000000
maturity = Date(10, June, 2026)
fixedRate = 0.05
spread = 0.0

#How to create the MX index here?
index = Euribor6M(forecastTermStructure)


fixedSchedule = Schedule(settlementDate, maturity,
                         fixedLegTenor, calendar,
                         fixedLegAdjustment, fixedLegAdjustment,
                         DateGeneration.Forward, False)
floatingSchedule = Schedule(settlementDate, maturity,
                            floatingLegTenor, calendar,
                            floatingLegAdjustment, floatingLegAdjustment,
                            DateGeneration.Forward, False)

swap = VanillaSwap(VanillaSwap.Receiver, nominal,
                   fixedSchedule, fixedRate, fixedLegDayCounter,
                   floatingSchedule, index, spread,
                   Actual360())
swap.setPricingEngine(swapEngine)

discountTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapCurve)
print('NPV')
print(swap.NPV())
print('Rate')
print(swap.fairRate()
shift = 0.0001

temp_fyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
temp_dyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
shiftedForwardCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_fyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(shift)))
shiftedDiscountCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_dyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(shift)))
discountTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedDiscountCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedForwardCurve)
P_p = swap.NPV()

temp_fyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
temp_dyc_handle = YieldTermStructureHandle(depoSwapCurve)
shiftedForwardCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_fyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(-shift)))
shiftedDiscountCurve = ZeroSpreadedTermStructure(temp_dyc_handle, QuoteHandle(SimpleQuote(-shift)))
discountTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedDiscountCurve)
forecastTermStructure.linkTo(shiftedForwardCurve)
P_m = swap.NPV()

dv01 = (P_m - P_p) / 2.0
print('Swap DV01')
print(dv01)
```

Comment: Why are you passing `NullCalendar()`? i assume you, Mexico has holidays.

Answer (score 2):

Same as you did for the other instance of the index, except you'll also have to pass the term structure:

```
index = IborIndex('TIIE', Period(28, Days), 2, MXNCurrency(),
                  NullCalendar(), Following, False, Actual360(),
                  forecastTermStructure)
```

As Dimitri commented, you might also use `Mexico()` instead of `NullCalendar()` in both places.